# Entering line break into legend header using ArcGIS Pro GUI

Tags: arcgis-pro, legend, heading, newline

I have a script that programmatically creates maps using a single layout. To keep everything consistent in my script, I'm trying to add a new line specifically to the legend header. Strangely, I can achieve this by adding a new line character to the header name, but the layout keeps the "\n" text. Here's an example screenshot below where I want a line break after the variable name "EPA_site_den" to separate it from the "(density)" text.

[image: Note the "\n" is still in the layout!]

Does anyone know how to achieve this without the "\n" text showing?

This is not a code related question. I added the details about code to indicate why I need to specifically change the legend header. However, I want to change the legend header using any ArcGIS Pro GUI tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text for the what you see in the Heading appears to be stored as part of the layer. I was able to place a new line break `\n` between the text by alter the property via [CIM](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm). I was unable to directly alter it via selecting the heading in the Contents pane and pressing F2. Any attempt to directly add a newline break seemed to be ignored.

The following code can be pasted into the Python command line window and will insert the line break, you just need to change the layer name in the code

```py
import arcpy

# Get project and then the active (open) map
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')
m = p.activeMap

# Get the layer you want to update heading, in this sample it is called TEST
layer = m.listLayers('TEST')[0]

# Return the layer's CIM definition
l_cim = layer.getDefinition('V2')

# Update heading
l_cim.renderer.heading = "EPA_site_den \n (density)"

# Push the changes back to the layer object
layer.setDefinition(l_cim)
```

Below is an example of the updated legend:

[image: Legend]

Comment: It worked for my vector layers, thank you! But for my raster layers, I had to try a different method and I'm getting stuck. Perhaps I should post this as a separate question but for my raster layers, my code looks like: 

`layer = m.listLayers('Brackish_ft_raw')[0]
l_cim = layer.getDefinition('V2')
colorizer = l_cim.colorizer

groups = colorizer.groups

for grp in groups:
    grp.heading = 'Shallow_brackish1 \n(probability)'   
    l_cim.colorizer = colorizer
    layer.colorizer = colorizer
    
    p.save()`

Comment: Yes post as separate question, you can always reference this Q&A. Indentation is important in python and its impossible to tell when you post in comments, so don't do it! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Based on Hornbydd's answer, I created a script that works on raster layers to solve the same problem.

```
# set up project and map
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = p.listMaps('Name')[0]

# editing header for a single layer
layer = m.listLayers('Brackish_ft_raw')[0]

# Return the layer's CIM definition
l_cim = layer.getDefinition('V2')

# Access the colorizer property of the CIMRasterLayer object
colorizer = l_cim.colorizer

# Access the groups property of the colorizer
groups = colorizer.groups

for grp in groups:
    grp.heading = 'Shallow_brackish \n(probability)'   
    l_cim.colorizer = colorizer
    
    # Push the changes back to the layer object
    layer.setDefinition(l_cim)
    p.save()
```

Note: I compared the .lyrx files of a raster and vector layer to identify the differences in changing headers between the two types of layers. The code I used for that was:

```
layer.saveACopy('testNOworksbrackishRAW.lyrx')
```